# rsync with inplace deletes the directory

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I have rsync executed continuously between 2 systems which has the tcp connection getting interrupted due to known reasons.
In a rare case, it so happens that the entire rsync destination directory is deleted and the data gets synced to alternative location.

The rsync option used is "-rpt -iP --stats --inplace" I read about --inplace being inconsistent with interrupted connection.

-rpt -iP --stats --inplace >> FAILS

Need help to come up with safest approach to avoid inconsistencies in rsync in an environment with frequent connection disruption

Comment: Do you really need to use `--inplace` ? For me `--inplace` has benefits only if you are syncing really big files to avoid full transfer but if your files are smaller then it's benefit goes away

Comment: The issue was seen even without --inplace. -P would also end up modifying the actual dest directory.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with simplest rsync `-avz --progress` if you can't do it then add `--stats` and try again. Even if you don't want compression you can remove "z"

Answer (score 6):

If you need a consistent way to syncing whole directory use:

```
rsync -avz \
    --partial \
    --partial-dir=.rsync-partial/ \
    --delay-updates \
    --delete \
    --stats \
    ...
```

[Linux man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) says about `--inplace`:

> This has several effects: (1) in-use binaries cannot be updated (either the OS will prevent this from happening, or binaries that attempt to swap-in their data will misbehave or crash), (2) the file's data will be in an inconsistent state during the transfer, (3) a file's data may be left in an inconsistent state after the transfer if the transfer is interrupted or if an update fails

So, `--inplace` can not be used for consistent syncing. Instead use **delay-updates** algorithm that guarantees that destination-dir changes will be implied only after successfully completed transfer.

Also you may decide to use `-a` instead of `-rpt`. `-a` param is equivalent to  `-rlptgoD` and this is complete params set for consistent syncing. `-vz` params useful for verbose output and compression while transfer (reducing traffic).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But I may also have to include mechanism to cleanup older partial directory.

Comment: @tss `rsync` will care about partial directory, you don't need to include special mechanism for it.